# Meteor packages -- how does it work?

Tags: meteor

I downloaded a Meteor Starter project called [MeteorAdmin](https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-admin).

In the root of its directory tree, you find a `packages` directory that contains few packages (`boostrap`, `comments`, few others) and also, in the `.meteor` directory there's a file called `packages` that defines the dependencies of this project.

What is the difference between them? What I found interesting is that `.meteor/packages` contains `bootstrap` as well. In theory shouldn't that be enough so that bootstrap would get downloaded to the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meteor packages file simply lists all of the apps dependencies as well as the load order of each (top to bottom). You can edit this file if you know what you are doing, but it's probably better to leave it alone until you are more familiar with Meteor.

The way you add packages is by typing `meteor add <package-name>` in your terminal and then it will be added to your project. Additionally, the name of the package will be added to the bottom of your packages file.

A meteor app can have local packages that are defined in the packages folder of the root directory. This project likely is implementing it's own bootstrap package and then added it with the meteor command I listed above. Once a local package is added to your project with the `meteor add` command it's package name will appear in the packages file just like packages from Atmosphere. I hope that answers your question... Let me know if you were looking for something more specific.

Comment: Interesting, can you teach me how to fish :) ? Is this in the official docs? Also what's the reason to add local packages, they actually do mention they edited bootstrap but not the other packages

Comment: The official docs talk a little bit about packages for sure. Local packages are useful for separating concerns. Some people even go so far as writing their entire app in small packages. Check out this repo to see an example https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope